# getting series of fx rates from a websie

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to automate the retrieval of fx rates from a website for a small list of currencies for a given date.

I would love some advice

I have tried two methods :-

1) updating fields on webpage and trying to get the rate
2) issuing a server request using xmlhttp

but neither has worked

the first method I tried was to update the fields on the page :-

```
objIE.navigate ("https://www.oanda.com/currency/converter/")

Do
    DoEvents
Loop Until objIE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE


objIE.document.getElementById("quote_currency_input").Value = "Utd. Arab Emir Dirham"
objIE.document.getElementById("base_currency_input").Value = "Pound Sterling"
objIE.document.getElementById("end_date_input").Value = "Apr 6, 2019"
objIE.document.getElementById("form_quote_currency_hidden").Value = "AED"
objIE.document.getElementById("form_base_currency_hidden").Value = "GBP"
objIE.document.getElementById("form_end_date_hidden").Value = "2019-04-06"
objIE.document.getElementById("form_end_date_hidden").FireEvent "onchange"

.Range("A1").Offset(i - 1, 1).Value = objIE.document.getElementById("base_amount_input").Value
```

Then I tried using xmlhttp :-

```
Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")

With xmlhttp
    .Open "POST", "https://www.oanda.com/currency/converter/", False
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    .send "update?base_currency_0=AUD&quote_currency=GBP&end_date=2019-04-06&view=details&id=1&action=C&"
    Debug.Print .responseText
End With
```

but I couldn't figure out how to just get the rate!!!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. The server responds with JSON (which VBA does not natively support, but there are libraries/modules available which will help you parse it).

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub GetRate()

    Dim xmlhttp As MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60 ' Add a reference for early binding.
    Set xmlhttp = New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60

    Const BASE_URL As String = "https://www.oanda.com/currency/converter/update?"

    Dim urlWithQueryString As String
    urlWithQueryString = BASE_URL & "base_currency_0=" & Application.EncodeURL("AUD") & "&quote_currency=" & Application.EncodeURL("GBP") & "&end_date=" & Application.EncodeURL("2019-04-06") & "&view=details&id=1&action=C"

    With xmlhttp
        .Open "GET", urlWithQueryString, True

        .setRequestHeader "Accept", "text/javascript, text/html, application/xml, text/xml, */*"
        .setRequestHeader "Referer", "https://www.oanda.com/currency/converter/"
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36"
        .setRequestHeader "X-Prototype-Version", "1.7"
        .setRequestHeader "X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest"
        .send
        .waitForResponse

        MsgBox .responseText
    End With
End Sub
```

- None of the query parameter values (in the above) needed URL encoding (no URL unsafe characters), but I did it anyway.
- You could refactor the above into a function which accepts arguments for `base_currency`, `quote_currency` and `end_date`.
- I couldn't figure out what purpose the parameters `id` and `action` serve. I could see `id` was increasing by 1 with each request that I made in my browser (maybe it's a client-sided counter of some sort -- or maybe it's used to facilitate request caching by the server).

Once you've parsed the response into a structure, I think you want the rates present in:

```
JSONresponse["data"]["rate_data"]["bidRates"][0]
```

---

If your version of Excel contains Power Query, you could instead use it to request the rate. The benefits would be that it can handle JSON (natively) and it can return an Excel table. The drawback would be that Power Query has its own programming language `M`, but the equivalent in `M` would be something like:

```
let
    url = "https://www.oanda.com/currency/converter/update",
    requestParameters = [base_currency_0 = "GBP", quote_currency = "AUD", end_date = "2019-04-06", view = "details", id = "1", action = "C"],
    requestHeaders = [
        Accept = "text/javascript, text/html, application/xml, text/xml, */*",
        Referer = "https://www.oanda.com/currency/converter/",
        #"User-Agent" = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36",
        #"X-Prototype-Version" = "1.7",
        #"X-Requested-With" = "XMLHttpRequest"
    ],
    request = Web.Contents(url, [Query = requestParameters, Headers = requestHeaders]),
    json = Json.Document(request),
    rate = json[data][rate_data][bidRates]{0}
in
    rate
```

Which you would implement (depending on Excel version) by: `Excel > Data > Get Data > From Other Sources > Blank Query > Advanced Editor (top left) > replace any code with code above > Close & Load (top left) > Load to new sheet`. (This would be more useful if you were loading more than just one value to the sheet.)